# Erlang Port Data Transfer Length

Tags: erlang, port

I am trying to evaluate php code through erlang using erlang ports. The problem is when Data to be evaluated is bigger then I am getting **parse error** from php. But if data is smaller then I am getting the correct output. I think when the Data length is bigger erlang is **truncating** the data before it is being sent to php for evaluation. Is there any limit on data length which can be sent or received on erlang port. Or is this error due to some other reason ?

I am using **open_port(PortName, PortSettings)** to open a new port and in PortSettings I am setting **[{packet,4},exit_status]** as my port options.

Answer (score 0):

The `{packet, 4}` tuple says the program launched to handle the other end of the port expects data in a 4-byte length-prefixed form. I don't see anything in the docs for the `php(1)` program that says it knows how to deal with such data. Probably the only reason it works for short inputs is that the length prefix looks kinda like ASCII if you squint, as long as the data you're sending is under 127 bytes. As soon as you go over that, PHP is probably running into a UTF-8 decoding error.

I'm pretty sure you want to say `spawn` here instead. This gets you standard Unix-like pipe interaction: data sent down the port goes to stdin on the launched process, and anything it sends to stdout comes back to your Erlang process.

The only problem doing it this way is that it re-launches `php(1)` on each transaction. This may seem expensive, but it's not too bad on any Unix type system, due to the relative efficiency of the `fork(2)` system call. If you're on Windows or you've benchmarked this and found that you really do need to build a FastCGI like system, you may be out of luck. There seems to be no `libphp` to embed PHP into a program you write to deal with packetized input, and no way to run `php(1)` in a way that lets it stay active on the other end of a port. You might be better off switching to a native Erlang templating system.

Also, note that the `exit_status` atom passed to `open_port()` does nothing unless you use `spawn`.

Comment: Sorry for missing details. Yes I am using spawn for portname and you are right that data sent is going to stdin and php is sending to stdout and that is coming back to erlang process. But I didn't understand when you say "The only problem doing it this way is that it re-launches php(1) on each transaction." Can you please explain this statement ?

Comment: I mean that `php(1)` isn't going to return the processed output (at least, not all of it) until it gets EOF on its stdin, which doesn't happen until your Erlang program calls `port_close()`. You then have to open a new PHP port to process another document. It would be more efficient if you could keep the PHP process running, which is what all the packet and line delimiter stuff is about when opening a port: a way to distinguish one transaction from the next. Since the standalone PHP interpreter doesn't support that, you have to re-launch it each time.